# Unknown warning while updating field

Tags: php, mysql

What sort of error is this, I mean while updating field if I use '', I am getting this error.

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\shadaab\aaction.php on line 87

ON 86-87 I have this query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM album WHERE name='$name'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0)
```

Comment: You forgot your error checking. Why does everybody always forget their error checking?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\messages.php on line 27](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936185/error-warning-mysql-num-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-give) (not to mention half a _million_ other questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty popular question on SO. It means your query failed, so `$result` is `false`.

Add

```
if (!$result){
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

To see what exactly error was. Most probably you have some illegal characters in `$name` variable. So, before embedding it into query string, you need to `mysql_escape_string()` it.

```
$name= mysql_escape_string($name);
```

Btw, your code is subject to SQL-injection. So, you'd better use [prepared_statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: How do you know? What is `$name`?

Comment: @john: Using mysql_real_escape_string warning message is not occuring. BUt query is not fired if I use the same.

Comment: It's just an assumption. It's certain that query fails because of SQL error, and the only obvious reason is the value of `$name`. It's wrapped in single-quotes, so it should be string. All PHP datatypes are casted to string in such a way that wouldn't crash that query (array become `Array`, object become `<ClassName>`, resource - something like `#Resource()` and so on). So, most likely `$name` is a string and it contains something that crash the query. Such as unescaped characters. It could be missing table, lack of permissions, removed db, etc.But simpliest explanation is unescaped characters

Comment: @Aditii what do you mean by `query is not fired`?

Comment: If I use mysql_real_escape_string($name) than my next update query is not running. THough I am not getting error but values are not updating . In case I don't use above function I have error in given above query but not in my next update query.

Comment: Some code samples and sample `$name` content could help a lot.

Comment: @J0HN let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2713/discussion-between-aditii-and-j0hn)

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) says:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or **FALSE on error**.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or **FALSE on error**.
>
> The returned result resource should be passed to mysql_fetch_array(), and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the returned data.
>
> Use mysql_num_rows() to find out how many rows were returned for a SELECT statement or mysql_affected_rows() to find out how many rows were affected by a DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, or UPDATE statement.
>
> mysql_query() will also fail and **return FALSE if the user does not have permission to access the table**(s) referenced by the query.

You should check that `$result !== false` first.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query` returns false on errors. Replace the first line with this (if you want to know the error):

```
mysql_query("SELECT name FROM album WHERE name='$name'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

For `SELECT statements mysql_query()` returns a resource on `success` and `FALSE` on failure. Check if `FALSE === $result`